# jQuery simply not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have a webpage including the following div:

```
<div class='book_box'>
    <table border=0 cellspacing=0>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'><img src='img/theseven.jpg' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>The Seven by Derek Edgington</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I have this Javascript code in my header:

```
$('.book_box').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('background', '#a8ff9a');
    }
);
```

...and it simply doesn't work. I have tested and ensured jQuery is loaded correctly and have performed some other operations with it. This code just seems to not work?

Comment: What do you want the code to perform? please ask an actual question.

Comment: I want all of my instances of the 'book_box' class to change background color upon mouse over, and then to change back when the mouse leaves.

Comment: The code is fine. It just needs to be in the document ready function AND make sure jQuery is actually included on your page.

Comment: Either you are missing a dom-ready or you overwrite the background-color somewhere in your table. The code is fine!

Comment: @SpaceBeers as I mentioned in the original question, jQuery is included fine. All i needed was the dom ready function. Thank you to those who pointed it out to me.

Comment: Ah of course. Never hurts to check though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the code in dom ready callback function. Or your code will executes before the `.book_box` div is ready.

```
$(function() {
  // put your code here.

});
```

It is the short cut of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // put your code here.

});
```

Comment: @Christoph Why not necessary?

Comment: You are the programmer of the hour! I couldn't find this solution anywhere! Could you explain briefly why this solution works?

Comment: It depends on where you insert the code. Dom-Ready is necessary e.g if you include the code in the head.

Comment: @Christoph Have you seen `And I have this Javascript code in my header:`? :)

Comment: @worsnupd I have added some explanation.

Comment: I know what to do and what not to do. I just wanted to point you to the fact, that domready is not always necessary. You don't need it if you are okay with sequential order or windowload.

Answer (score 4):

Without any change in code , ITs working for me here is demo on JSFiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/76bEw/)

Suggestion : just make use of`$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.book_box').hover( function() {
      alert('abc');
      $(this).css('background', '#ffffff'); 
    },
    function() { 
      alert('abc1');
      $(this).css('background', '#a8ff9a'); 
    } 
  );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 $('.book_box').hover(
function() {
    $(this).css(backgroundColor, '#ffffff');
},
function() {
    $(this).css(backgroundColor, '#a8ff9a');
}

);
```

Comment: This is the same as what I had, what I needed was xdazz's solution.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox and Opera on Linux it is working all right, but maybe you try this:

```
$(function() {
            $('.book_box table').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
            },
            function() {
                $(this).css('background', '#a8ff9a');
            }
        );
});
```

Have you took a look at the (Firefox) error console?